# How to iterate over mulltiple files containing different ranges with TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a collection of files. Each file has 1 second data. Furthermore, the files are not periodic, i.e. they are not daily files. For example, one file may contain a day and a half of data, whereas the next may contain 3 days and 2 hours; gaps may exist between files and within them. Another issue is that it is not practical to load all the files in memory at the same time.

Here is a concrete example that shows the problem. The following dataframe has a day and half of 1 second data:

```
index = pd.date_range('now', periods=60*60*24*1.5, freq='1S')
data_a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index)), index=index, columns=['data'])
```

The next dataframe starts where the previous one left off and it has two days of data:

```
index = pd.date_range(data_a.index[-1] + pd.Timedelta('1S'), periods=60*60*24*2, freq='1S')
data_b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index)), index=index, columns=['data'])
```

Lets create 10 minute iterators on each dataframe and [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) them:

```
ia = iter(data_a.groupby(TimeGrouper('10Min')))
ib = iter(data_b.groupby(TimeGrouper('10Min')))
iaib = chain(ia, ib)
```

The desired behaviour if we iterate over `iaib` is to see each group key (and its data) only once, but this is not the case.

```
seen = {}
for name, group in iaib:
    count = seen.get(name, 0)
    seen[name] = count + 1

seen_twice = {key: value for key, value in seen.items() if value > 1}
```

The contents of `seen_twice` are:

```
{Timestamp('2017-06-02 08:50:00', freq='10T'): 2}
```

In this example, `2017-06-02 08:50:00` is the key of the last group of `data_a` and the first group of `data_b`.

How do I iterate by 10 minute groups over all the files without repeating groups at the edges of the files?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, hopefully I've improved the question.

Answer (score 1):

The solution has two parts: one is to handle all the files as a single dataset; the other is to account for the fact that a 10 minute group can be split between the end of one file and the start of the next.

These are the required imports:

```
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.resample import TimeGrouper
```

#### Handle all the files as a single dataset

This function returns an iterator over the 10 minute groups of the given file:

```
def make_iterator(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col='timestamp', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
    return iter(df.groupby(TimeGrouper('10Min')))
```

The above function is used to create an iterator of iterators with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). Given a list of files a single iterator over all the 10 min groups of the collection of files can be created like so:

```
files = ... # list obtained by os.listdir() or glob.glob()    
iterator_of_single_file_group_iterators = map(make_iterator, files)
chained_file_group_iterator = chain.from_iterable(iterator_of_single_file_group_iterators)
```

#### Account for the fact that a group can be split between the end of one file and the start of the next

However, the above iterator is not aware of 10 minute groups that span two files. The following class addresses that problem:

```
class TimeGrouperChainDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self._has_more = True
        self._last_item = next(self.iterator)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self._has_more:
            raise StopIteration
        try:
            return self._next()
        except StopIteration:
            self._has_more = False
            if self._last_item is not None:
                return self._last_item
            raise StopIteration

    def _next(self):
        new_key, new_data = next(self.iterator)

        last_key, last_data = self._last_item
        if new_key == last_key:
            data = pd.concat([last_data, new_data])
            try:
                self._last_item = next(self.iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                self._has_more = False
            return new_key, data
        else:
            self._last_item = new_key, new_data
            return last_key, last_data
```

Note that the implementation is entirely dependent on the pandas `groupby` API. To use it, create an instance of the class with the above chained iterators:

```
iterator = TimeGrouperChainDecorator(chained_file_group_iterator)

for name, group in iterator:
    # do something with each 10 minute group
```

My implementation may not be perfect so any feedback is welcome. I've published a [snippet with 3 tests](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/pablo_esteban/8nzRK).